# JQuery clone div and insert below the last one

Tags: jquery

Does anyone please know why is the cloned div always being inserted after the first div and not after the last added (cloned) div? I have also tried many variation with simple javascript but without success.

Please see the example:

```js
document.getElementById("add-div").onclick = function() {
  $('#to-be-cloned').clone().insertAfter($('#to-be-cloned:last'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="to-be-cloned">
  <select>
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button id="add-div">Add div</button>
```

Example at: https://codepen.io/azej/pen/YLMdKG

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because you're cloning the element which has an `id`, which leads to duplicate `id` attributes in the DOM. When selecting by that `id` only the first element will be found.

To fix this use a `class` instead, then use the `:first` and `:last` selectors as required:

```js
$("#add-div").click(function() {
  $('.to-be-cloned:first').clone().insertAfter('.to-be-cloned:last');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="to-be-cloned">
  <select>
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button id="add-div">Add div</button>
```

Also note that you can provide a selector string to `insertAfter()` - you don't need to create another entire jQuery object.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped